# Set the value from database to Jcombobox populated with enum

Tags: java, swing, enums, jcombobox

I have JCombobox and an enum class BloodGroup. I populate `JComboBox` with `enum.value()` method. I save to combobox seleted item in database A+ and A-.

Now i retrive the data from database and want to set value in Jcombox.

Check the code below and line `cmbGender.setSelectedItem("Value from Database like A+");`

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class ComboxExample extends JFrame
{

public static void main(String[] args )
{
    JComboBox cmbBloodGroup = new JComboBox(BloodGroup.values());

    ComboxExample CE = new ComboxExample();
    CE.setSize(300,200);
    CE.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    CE.add(cmbBloodGroup);
    CE.setVisible(true);

    cmbBloodGroup.setSelectedItem("Value from Database like F");

}
}


enum BloodGroup
{
    A_Positive("A+"),A_Negative("A-"),
    B_Postive("B+"),B_Negative("B-"),
    O_Postive("O+"),O_Negative("O-"),
    AB_Positive("AB+"),AB_Negative("AB-");

private final String name;

private BloodGroup(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return The string representation of this element in the enumeration.
 */

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return this.name;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've added my answer, look at it, please

Answer (score 3):

> Now i retrive the data from database and want to set value in Jcombox.

Check out [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/).

It shows how to do this without using Enums. Basically if you want to be able to set a value in the combo box, then the Object you add to the ComboBoxModel must implement the `equals(...)` method so the combo box can find the Object to select.

Comment: +1 for comparable and equal method in the item class, but I'm searching for solving my problem using the enum class. If i use the above method i have to change so many in my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
cmbGender.setSelectedItem(Gender.valueOf("F"));
```

`valueOf` returns an object from `enum` if it exists otherwise you will get the `IllegalArgumentException` exception.

```
1. Gender.valueOf("F") == Gender.F
2. Gender.valueOf("A") == throwing an exception
```

---

```
public static BloodGroup get(String value) {
    switch (value) {
        case "A+": return A_Positive;
        ...
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

And as a result:

```
BloodGroup.get("A+") == BloodGroup.A_Positive;
```

Comment: What if The constant name is change. Like Blood group name.
Enum bloodgroup{ A_Positve(A+), A_Negative(A-) }
how i will get the value, because from database i get A+. which will become bloodgroup.valueOf("A+"). but to set the item i need the code,
bloodgroup.valueOf(A_Positive)

Comment: @ AndrewI get the error no enum constant BloodGroup.A+

Comment: I have 6 enum classes in my Application. I have to write get method for all the classes? I want to do it in a nice and elgant way.

Comment: @AqeelHaider, yes, you should do that or you have to name constants as String values